# Open Source Alternative to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, open-source

There is already an alternative to Dropbox, namely [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/).

Is there open source alternative to Google Drive? Specifically for document creation where on could create documents/spreadsheet/presentation and store it on the cloud.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what features of Google Drive you want? What have you looked at already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [OX App Suite](https://www.ox.io/) from Open-Xchange. It's very similar to Google Drive, but from what I have read the community version is open source.

More detailed information can be found here in the [OX Knowledge Base](http://knowledgebase.open-xchange.com/start.html).

Here's a quick preview of what it looks like on different devices:

[image]

Comment: Open-Xchange is largely email-based, like a replacement for Microsoft Exchange. How would this act as a replacement for Google Drive?

Comment: @AndrewLott He was looking for something that worked where you had a storage and ability to edit files through the website like google drive and not just store files. this is why i suggested open-exchange: [OX Text](https://www.ox.io/ox_text)

Comment: Right, I see what you mean now. I've edited your answer to be a bit more clear and included the screenshot you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

For detail information  http://www.pcworld.com/article/2031457/ready-for-a-new-google-docs-alternative-meet-open-source-ox-documents.html

Open-Xchange launches open source browser-based Office productivity suite, OX Documents

visit http://www.open-xchange.com/misc/singlenews.html?tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=377&cHash=5ca0ddcd1137ce44adfa18a79dd55195